# Multiple 301 Redirect for HTTPS URL

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, https

I have a client website which has been shifted to HTTPS now. The default URL is **http:// business.com** which still faces canonical issue. I need to redirect its www version to the default URL and all of them the the final HTTPS URL i.e. **https:// business.com** . I have written simple codes in .htaccess in the past but combining more than one code is a problem for me. I have tried to combine the code in the following 2 samples, and will appreciate if you can help me in reviewing the same:

Code1:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.business.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http:// business.com/$1 [R=301]

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https:// business.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

OR Code2:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.business (DOT)com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http:// business (DOT)com/$1 [R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Here I have included space after http:// as I was not able to post otherwise, thanks in advance.

Regards,
Rahul

Comment: Please review to assist me.

Comment: Hi friends, I am stuck with the redirection code, please help me.